# What are the rules about two verbs in active/passive conversion?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

There are many types in this I suppose. Like two clauses , or verbs with prepositions etc.
e.g - 
Smoke and flames engulfed the area and made rescue operations difficult.

What will be it's passive voice ?

Comment: The most natural is the following: *The rescue operations were made difficult by the smoke and flames that engulfed the area.* But your question is unclear. Are you asking to convert both verbs into the passive (which would be an unnatural language exercise) or just one (which would be normal)? Also, explain why you are asking and what you've already considered.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to change *made difficult* into the more obviously active verb *hampered.*

> Smoke and flames engulfed the area and hampered rescue operations.

Here, your two active verbs can each be passivised, retaining their respective agents and patients.

> The area was engulfed by smoke and flames.
>   Rescue operations were hampered by smoke and flames.

If you want to retain **both** passive forms, then the agent *smoke and flames* needs to come at the end but you still need two patients:

> The area was engulfed by, and rescue operations were hampered by, smoke and flames.
>   The area was engulfed, and rescue operations were hampered, by smoke and flames.

That is very awkward. The usual form is to retain an active verb in a relative clause:

> The area was engulfed by smoke and flames, which hampered rescue operations.
>   Rescue operations were hampered by [the] smoke and flames which engulfed the area.

Note the comma! The British Council has [notes on relative clauses](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/relative-pronouns-and-relative-clauses), which can be applied to these sentences:

> 1. We use relative clauses to make clear which person or thing we are talking about:
>
>    > Rescue operations were hampered by [the] smoke and flames which engulfed the area.
> 2. We also use relative clauses to give more information about a person, thing or situation:
>
>    > The area was engulfed by smoke and flames, which hampered rescue operations.

Comment: If you wanted to retain the flavour of your original you could say: "Here, your two active verbs can each be passivised, converting their patients into subjects" or  "Here, your two active verbs can each be passivised, converting their patients - objects in the active sentences- into subjects.", or something like that. If you wanted. (That's kind of what I understood you to aiming at). You can delete this comment  after you've read it!